# Normal Word Style is missing

Tags: styles

Normal style was erased from the style selection and I cannot get it back. I reload the software (office 365) and it is still missing. How do I get back to the original download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably somehow changed the default word template. To reset this you'll have to delete the files NORMAL.DOTM and BUILDINGBLOCKS.DOTX when Word is closed, and so the'll be rebuilt to the original state when you start Word the next time.

**Normal.DOTM** and **BuildingBlocks.DOTX** usually reside in `C:\Users\%your user name%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates` ("%your user name%" shall be replaced with your login username)

Comment: Thank you. BuildingBlocks.dotx did not exist, but normal was restored by erasing normal.dotm.

Comment: @RRR glad to hear. If my answer answered you question mark it as the correct answer.